# How to add a panoramic image in the google cardboard application?

Tags: android, opengl-es, google-cardboard

I want to create an application where a panoramic image is displayed in the google cardboard like a 3D picture.I have taken the sample cardboad code provided by google.How do I add a panoramic image in the views instead of the floor and the cube?

Comment: Also can this be done using OpenGL or we need to use Unity for this?

Comment: On Android Native Cardboard app development, you can use Android Cardboard SDK and Android Studio as IDE is recommended. However you might need to learn OpenGL ES SDK and things like GLSurfaceView.
By using Unity+Cardboard SDK to develop VR apps, you don't have to worry on how to draw/ render your image/3D objects since it is made for game development.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at this example application:
https://github.com/ejeinc/RajawaliCardboardExample

It is using the Rajawali framework for the OpenGL stuff. This makes things really easy.
https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali